# Laravel query exclude data

Tags: php, laravel

I have query where i get all users with certain roles and it's working fine, what I need now is to exclude those users who has been saved in third table already and just return users without row in third table.

## Logic

1. Users table (`user has many roles`, `user hasOne manager`)
2. Roles Table (`role belongsTo user`)
3. Managers Table (`managers belongsTo user`)

**First time**

User who has role of `manager` I return them all. (let say 2 users)

I save one of them in `managers` table.

**Second time**

User who has role of `manager` I return them all.

I save one of them in `managers` table.

## Issue

In second time i should only get `1` user as I previously saved one of them into `managers` table. But with my current code I do still get 2 users.

## Code

```
$users = User::whereHas("roles", function($q) {
  $q->where("name", "manager");
})->get();
```

> SQL output of code above is:

```
"select * from `users` where exists (select * from `roles` inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `users`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`model_id` and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = ? and `name` = ?) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is not possible with the information you've provided. How do you tell if an entry in `managers` table is the same as the entry in `users` table? Why is the same person in two tables? If these are separate entities, just delete from the users table when you insert into the managers table.

Comment: @miken32 not sure if you get the logic, users id is stored in managers table. so when users with role of `manager` has his/her id in `managers` table then i filter it out. that's how.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I predict that you have this database structure:

```
User
user_id(PK) | ...

Role
role_id(PK) | user_id | name | ...

Manager
manager_id | user_id | ...
```

So, you need to query all users, who have role='manager', but is not in table manager.

Just do a left join:

```
$users = User::query()
  ->select("user.*")
  ->join("Role", "user.user_id", "=", "role.user_id")
  ->leftJoin("Manager", "manager.user_id", "=", "user.user_id")
  ->whereNull("manager.manager_id")
  ->where("role.name", "=", "manager")
  ->get();
```

It will generate this SQL query:

```
SELECT user.*
FROM
  user
  INNER JOIN role ON role.user_id=user.user_id
  LEFT JOIN manager ON manager.user_id=user.user_id
WHERE manager.manager_id IS NULL AND role.name='manager'
```